# Symfony can't decide which class requires

Tags: php, arrays, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

This is my error:

> The form's view data **is expected to be an instance of class
>   My\Bundle\Entity\Tags, but is an instance of class
>   Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection**. You can avoid this error
>   by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view
>   transformer that transforms an instance of class
>   Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection to an instance of
>   My\Bundle\Entity\Tags

and this is my form builder

```
 $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('tags','collection',array(
                        'data_class' => 'My\Bundle\Entity\Tags'
                        )
            )
            ->add('save','submit')
        ;
```

I changed `data_class` to `null` ( only that ) and I'm getting error:

> The form's view data **is expected to be of type scalar, array or an
>   instance of \ArrayAccess, **but is an instance of class
>   My\Bundle\Entity\Tags***. You can avoid this error by setting the
>   "data_class" option to "My\Bundle\Entity\Tags" or by adding a view
>   transformer that transforms an instance of class My\Bundle\Entity\Tags
>   to scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess.

I've tried with a transformer, so it looked like this :

```
    $transformer = new TagTransformer($this->entityManager);
    $builder
        ->add(
            $builder->create(
                'tags','collection',array(
                    'data_class' => 'My\Bundle\Entity\Tags'
                    )
            )->addModelTransformer($transformer)
        );
```

and transformer:

```
public function transform($tag)
{
    if (null === $tag) {
        return "";
    }

    return $tag->toArray();
}
```

and changed `data_class` to `null` again. What I get:

> The form's view data **is expected to be of type scalar, array or an
>   instance of \ArrayAccess, but is an instance of class
>   My\Bundle\Entity\Tags**. You can avoid this error by setting the
>   "data_class" option to "My\Bundle\Entity\Tags" or by adding a view
>   transformer that transforms an instance of class My\Bundle\Entity\Tags
>   to scalar, array or an instance of \ArrayAccess.

When I changed `data_class` to `My\Bundle\Entity\Tags`

> The form's view data **is expected to be an instance of class
>   My\Bundle\Entity\Tags, but is a(n) array**. You can avoid this error by
>   setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view
>   transformer that transforms a(n) array to an instance of
>   My\Bundle\Entity\Tags.

Well.. I mean... wtf? What am I doing wrong? How can I change that?

**Edit:**

My user entity:

```
class User
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tags", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $tags;

// methods, etc..
}
```

Comment: post your tags declaration in your entity

Comment: Pretty sure you will need to make yourself a TagFormType.  I don't see how S2 will be able to make a form for you Tag(s) entity without one.  Follow the example in the cookbook:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: And rename Entity\Tags to Tag otherwise it will drive you crazy.

Comment: well I can't follow the tutorial because I need to: render collection as multiple choice list AND as a multiple text inputs. And also I do have a TagFormType, but it has only one field, which is "title". @DerickF I've edited my post, is this is what You meant?

Answer (score 4):

So the reason you're getting errors is because you're using the collection field type a bit incorrect.  First of all, the collection field type doesn't support data_class.  When you say

```
->add('tags','collection',array(
    'data_class' => 'My\Bundle\Entity\Tags'
     )
)
```

you're basically saying that tags (which is an array collection according to your declaration) is actually a tag.  If you look at the documentation for the collection type you'll notice that data_class isn't even a supported option.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

so if you want to render a multiple choice list of tags you're looking for the entity type, however these are tags, and if you have any sort of decent site you'll probably have way more than a multiple choice list would be practical for.  design wise you want to just have an auto-completer to show what tags already exist with the typed text as you type and then just have the user press enter to add the tag whether is exists or not.  then above the auto completer you'd show the tags already added and have and x next to them that they can press on to remove the tag.

you can cheat by just having tags field in your form be a unmapped text type and use javascript to combine the tags together into a string on form submit, then in your action turn the string into your tags.

Comment: well that's actually a great idea. but if user is going to add multiple tags ( no limits for that ) don't I need collection type? Because I couldn't find the way to do that with entity type.

Comment: well you won't get this functionality out of the box.  it requires a mix of javascript and symfony.  one way is to have a hidden field called tagsString and have that field be un-mapped.  when a user hit submit, use javascript to combine the tags into a single string that gets passed as the value of the hidden tagsString form field. And then when you handle your form turn the tagsString into tags.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay here but would this work for you ?

```
 $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('tags','collection',array(
                    'type' => '**{{ NAME OF THE FORM }}**',
                )
            )
            ->add('save','submit');
```